# How to decide whether a GPU card is being used?

Tags: cuda

In CUDA, is there any runtime API that will tell whether a GPU device is being used or not? And whether the user is from video display or a GUGPU application? And what is the GPU occupancy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On linux at least, you can use the program `nvidia-smi` to see the current memory use, and if any compute processes are running. Think though that the status about compute processes is only supported on a selected number of graphics cards, e.g. tesla.

Comment: Thanks for the great information! But, do you know any cuda runtime API can do this?

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the NVIDIA management library, NVML: https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-management-library-nvml

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't show exactly what is using it, MSI Afterburner on Windows will show you the core usage, memory usage, fan speed, and temperature of GPU's in a system (NV or otherwise.)